# Binding data for React component from external API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs, npm

My React component renders based on the local JSON config file. The JSON file consists of label text, various styles for labels, format of data (like number, negative number, etc.). The actual data to be displayed along with label should be get from external API. My Component will be look like this

```js
var WidgetLabel = React.createClass({  
  render: function() {
    return (
      <span>
        <p className="card-stats-title"><i className="mdi-editor-attach-money"></i>{this.props.data.title}</p>       
      </span>
    );  
  }
});

var WidgetDataWrapper = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <h4 class="card-stats-number">{this.props.api_data_value}</h4>;
  }
});
```

```html
<div className="col s12 m6 l3">
        <div className="card">
          <div className={rndmClassName}>
            <WidgetLabel label_data={this.props.widget_label} />
            <WidgetDataWrapper widget_data_config={this.props.widget_data_config} widget_api_data={this.props.widget_api_data} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Where the WidgetLabel will be array of values in JSON file and the format of data will be in JSON file. I need to fetch the data from an API to each label.

My final result for the component will be

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l3">
   <div class="card">
       <p class="card-stats-title">{label_text_from_json}</p>
       <h4 class="card-stats-number">{data_this_label_from_api}</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
       <p class="card-stats-title">{label_text_from_json}</p>
       <h4 class="card-stats-number">{data_this_label_from_api}</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
       <p class="card-stats-title">{label_text_from_json}</p>
       <h4 class="card-stats-number">{data_this_label_from_api}</h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

I stuck with whether we can do this with React or not? As I am beginner to react js can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't come bundled with AJAX utilities, but you can use native `XMLHttpRequest` or `jQuery.ajax` to fetch JSON data from an API. You could take two different approaches to this problem:

A) Fetch the JSON data, then initialize your component passing the JSON response as props. Example using jQuery for brevity and a stateless component:

```
$.getJSON('api_url', function( response ){
    ReacDOM.render( <MyComponent {...response } />, document.getElementById('wrapper') );
});


var MyComponent = (props) => (
        <div className="card">
          <div className={props.rndmClassName}>
            <WidgetLabel label_data={props.widget_label} />
            <WidgetDataWrapper widget_data_config={props.widget_data_config} widget_api_data={props.widget_api_data} />
          </div>
        </div>
       );
```

- this is a good approach if you just want to render the component using configuration from external resource and do not need to update it later

B) Initialize the component, fetch data in `componentDidMount()` and set the response as state.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
       return { config : null }
    },
    componentDidMount(){
       $.getJSON( $.getJSON('api_url', (response) => {
           this.isMounted() && this.setState({ config : response });
       });
    },
    render(){
       return(
        <div className="card">
          <div className={rndmClassName}>
            { this.state.config && <WidgetLabel label_data={this.state.config.widget_label} /> }
            { this.state.config && <WidgetDataWrapper widget_data_config={this.state.config.widget_data_config} widget_api_data={this.state.config.widget_api_data} /> }
          </div>
        </div>
       );
    } 
});

ReacDOM.render( <MyComponent />, document.getElementById('wrapper') ); });
```

- this would be better if the component is dynamic and should reflect further updates to the state.

Comment: Thanks pawel. I try the second approach. It works fine for me. Thanks for the detailed explanation.